# ClickOnce publishing with .NET core pre-requisite

Tags: dll, clickonce, .net-core

My application (set to .NET framework 4.5.1) uses a nuget package that has dependency on .net core. When I try to publish the ClickOnce application, in the pre-requisites, I do not find any entry for .Net Core. How can I resolve this ?

If I go ahead and publish it, the application is unable to resolve System.Runtime.dll version 4.1.0.0 (I'm guessing the issue is with the pre-requisites).

Note: When I try the build directly from Visual Studio, I do not face any error.

Comment: You should try to add "System.Runtime" as an assembly reference and copy local. There is no need to add pre-requisite.

Comment: Since you're on .NET core, maybe you can consider a self-contained deployment? eg http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx If you go that route, then you eliminate the prerequisite altogether.